# Node Memory Issue when reading File

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

Just trying to upload a file (PDF). Someone noticed an issue when they tried to upload a 65mb file but I am noticing that when I go over 30mb I get errors in the console of VS code. Please see the stack trace from the error. I am just wondering is there another way to do this to avoid the memory crash with large files? Someone mentioned Streams and I did try but with no luck.
If you need anymore info, I will be happy to provide it. Thank you :)

Code:

```
import { readFile, readFileSync, writeFileSync } from 'fs-extra';
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
import { Readable } from 'stream';

import { Customer } from 'app/entities';

export const encryptFile: (
  fsPath: string,
  encryptionKey: string,
) => Promise<void> = async (fsPath, encryptionKey) => {
  if (!encryptionKey) throw new Error('Customer encryption key not found');

  const fileData = await readFile(fsPath);
  const dataBase64 = fileData.toString('base64');
  const encryptedFile = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(dataBase64, encryptionKey);
  const buffer = Buffer.from(encryptedFile.toString(), 'base64');
  writeFileSync(fsPath, buffer);
};
```

Stack trace:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[15084:000001BC6302C4B0]   287751 ms: Mark-sweep 1053.9 (1070.7) -> 1053.9 (1067.2) MB, 718.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu 
= 0.602, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested
[15084:000001BC6302C4B0]   288447 ms: Mark-sweep 1053.9 (1067.2) -> 1053.9 (1067.2) MB, 696.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu 
= 0.413, current mu = 0.000) last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000003DE8C2DC5C1]
    1: StubFrame [pc: 000003DE8C95C882]
Security context: 0x032fc8b1e6e9 <JSObject>
    2: DoJoin(aka DoJoin) [0000032FC8B05E91] [native array.js:1] [bytecode=00000333C45FB9D1 offset=182](this=0x02f50b7826f1 <undefined>,l=0x01df193c2dc1 <JSArray[60171968]>,m=60171968,A=0x02f50b7828c9 <true>,w=0x02f50b7829f1 <String[0]: >,v=0x02f50b7829a1 <false>)
    3: Join(aka Join) [0000032FC8B05EE1] [native arra...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6E0D47DDA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4506
 2: 00007FF6E0D22876 node::MakeCallback+4534
 3: 00007FF6E0D231F0 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF6E103B6BE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF6E103B5EF v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF6E1221DE4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9620
 7: 00007FF6E12202AB v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2651
 8: 00007FF6E134A2B8 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRawArray+56
 9: 00007FF6E134AC32 v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArrayWithFiller+66
10: 00007FF6E10C82DF v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::NewInternal+63
11: 00007FF6E10C8252 v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity+226
12: 00007FF6E10C8811 v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NumberDictionary,v8::internal::NumberDictionaryShape>::Add+129
13: 00007FF6E13652D7 v8::internal::Factory::NewCallHandlerInfo+49095
14: 00007FF6E10BCF88 v8::internal::SharedFunctionInfo::SetScript+23528
15: 00007FF6E109FF33 v8::internal::JSReceiver::class_name+20595
16: 00007FF6E133B539 v8::internal::wasm::WasmCodeManager::LookupCode+15273
17: 00007FF6E1248BFC std::vector<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64,v8::internal::ZoneAllocator<v8::internal::compiler::MoveOperands * __ptr64> >::_Umove+57468
18: 000003DE8C2DC5C1
```

Now trying this but its still not working correctly:
Getting this error:

```
UnknownErrorException {name: "UnknownErrorException", message: "PDFDocument: Stream must have data", details: "Error: PDFDocument: Stream must have data"}
```

```
export const encryptFile: (
  fsPath: string,
  encryptionKey: string,
) => Promise<void> = async (fsPath, encryptionKey) => {
  if (!encryptionKey) throw new Error('Customer encryption key not found');
  let dataBase64 = '';
  const aes = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKey);
  const read = createReadStream(fsPath);
  const write = createWriteStream(fsPath);
  
  const trans =  new Transform();
  trans._transform = (data, _, done) => {
    dataBase64 += data.toString();
    done(null, dataBase64);
  }
  console.log('dataBase64 ' + dataBase64)
  read.pipe(trans).pipe(aes).pipe(write);
};
```

Comment: try `read.pipe(writer); ` if this works you need to pass buffer as 2nd argument in done function. You can convert encrypted string to Buffer also.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you are getting errors for large files only. It seems an memory issue for large buffers.
I'd suggest you to create streams and pipe them to execute all three operations (Read, encrypt & write).

If you could share your code snippet with streams usage, that'd be helpful to understand the problem why it didn't work.

Thanks,

Comment: Im trying pipe but not getting very far. Trying to work my way through it but getting issues like: "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'."

Comment: Yeah, so you might be some minor things. Could you post the snippet here? We can take a look.

Comment: edited the question to include streams attempt. Not sure of how to pipe the streams as you mentioned.

Comment: I mentioned to use it like that only. Here are some reference examples, see if these are useful: 

https://gist.github.com/chris-rock/335f92742b497256982a

http://codewinds.com/blog/2013-08-20-nodejs-transform-streams.html#encrypting_data_stream_with_aes-256

Comment: I think, the error you are getting because you have called `done(null, "")` with empty data in callback. 

So next write stream process is throwing exception.

Comment: The last code I posted is working with images but not with PDFs.

Comment: I think, we should  append data in `dataBase64` variable. LIke : `dataBase64 += data.toString();`

Beacuse there data is coming in smaller chunks.

Comment: And again you should create a new writable stream instead of writeSync method  & pipe it with rest of two processes.

Comment: I edited the code again and put it up above. Its still not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const encryptFile = async (fsPath, encryptionKey) => {
 if (!encryptionKey) throw new Error('Customer encryption key not found');
 
 const read = fs.createReadStream(fsPath);
 const aes = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', encryptionKey);
 const write = fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf');
 
 read.pipe(aes).pipe(write);
};

encryptFile('a.pdf', 'dummy-secret-id');
```

This works for me, without using transform. Do you really need to transform data to `base 64` ?

Comment: Not working for me unfortunately. The pdf is not in the right format and cant be opened.

Comment: Did you copy the same code which I have added? 
In your snippet, the issue I saw was you have same `fspath` for Read & write streams.

Comment: Yes the file does not open properly in my application.

Comment: ive realised that the way you are suggesting is not reading the file at all. Zero bytes.

Comment: The above example is working fine for me.
 
Did you fix this `const read = createReadStream(fsPath); const write = createWriteStream(fsPath);`?

You had mentioned same path for read & write stream.

Comment: Hmm yes i think this is it. Is there no way with this solution to use the same path+file as createReadStream, to overwrite it? I tried {flags: 'w'} but it didnt work.

Comment: I think, it's not possible with streams. Since we don't read the entire content in one go. 
So Either you'll need to copy / read entire file in a buffer and then re-write the same file or you can write it first & then re-name it. 
If that works.